# Нужно скрыть div с сгенерированным id

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
hideNote = function functionName(hideNum) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(hideNum)));
    console.log(obj.id); //правильный id
    var a = obj.id;
    var ind = $(this).attr('a');
$('div [id='+ind+']' ).hide();/*
    var divToHide = document.getElementsById(obj.id);
    divToHide.style.visibility="hidden";
    //element.style.visibility = 'hidden';*/
},
```

Нужно скрыть div с определнным id, полученным из `localStorage`.
Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: У вас `ind` - это аттрибут `a`, при чём тут `id`?

Comment: Может быть `$('#'+obj.id).hide()`?

Answer (score 2):

Если obj.id содержит правильный id то его и используйте, и не нужно лишнего писать

```
$('#'+obj.id ).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть  несколько способов:

1.js + свойство css

```
 var elem1 = document.getElementById(obj.id);
 elem1.style.display = 'none';
```

2.jquery

```
$('#' + obj.id).hide();
```